# Applescript и автозамена текста

Tags: applescript

Я работаю в компании, где половина половина людей работает на маках, а половина на винде. При этом очень часто нужно делиться файлами прям ссылками на сервере, ибо файлы весят очень много. Естественно, при обмене ссылками между Маком и Виндой путь до файла нельзя просто скопировать и вставить в проводник или Finder и нужно доходить до файла руками, поэтому существует острая нужда в следующей штуке: при наличии текстового пути я его выделяю, и прожимаю скрипт, и у меня в буфер обмена копируется уже преобразованный путь, который мне остается либо вставить к себе (или просто переходит по нему сразу). Или наоборот, имеющийся маковский путь преобразовать и скинуть тем, кто на винде. Т.е. и того 2 скрипта. Вот примеры путей до одного и того же файла:

smb://company.com/Projects/S_288/09_Bolnice/

P:\S_288\09_Bolnice\

P: = Projects, что оно и понятно.

Подобная задача уже как-то задавалась в английской части форума (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276094/convert-mac-to-windows-paths-and-visa-versa-for-sharing-with-colleagues) но тот скрипт не работает должным образом, потому что тянется с 2011.

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос про то, как лучше реализовать или что не так с тем скриптом, что указан выше по ссылке. С Applescript никогда ранее не приходилось сталкиваться.